How to disable Smart Copy/Paste everywhere and/or in an individual app with Terminal?
Does anyone know how I can disable Smart Copy/Paste globally (or within an individual app's settings) using Terminal?
I know I can do this in the GUI for apps that support it (e.g. Safari, TextEdit) by going to the menubar ► Edit ► Substitutions ► toggling the checkbox for Smart/Copy Paste but this is suboptimal.
In other words, could this setting be edited via a plist somewhere or with the defaults command?
